# How to enable a function only if the parameter is dereferencable to a certain type?

Tags: c++, c++11, types

I am making a function template:

```
template <typename T>
void foo (T arg1) {}
```

But I want to make sure T is deferencable to type Foo, so `arg1` needs to be either:

```
Foo * //This case T = Foo*
```

Or

```
Any type X which implements `*` operator which returns a Foo/Foo&/Foo&&
```

So I need something like:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T arg1, std::enable_if<std::is_same<typeid(*arg1), typeid(Foo)>::value> * = 0) {}
```

But this does not compile and complains:

```
typecheck.cpp:6:54: error: use of parameter âarg1â outside function body
 void foo(T arg1, std::enable_if<std::is_same<typeid(*arg1), typeid(Foo)>::value> * = 0) {}
                                                      ^
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: One thing to note. `Foo*` dereferences to a `Foo&`, which will impact the test you're using.

Comment: @DaveS You are right... that's why `is_convertible` is more appropriate than `is_same` here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should prefer is_convertible instead of is_same to catch sub classes of Foo, the enable_if in the template argument list instead of the function arguments or return type is also easier to read.

```
template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<decltype( *std::declval<T>() ), Foo>::value>::type >
void foo(T arg1);
```

less garbage in c++14 :

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<decltype( *std::declval<T>() ), Foo>::value> >
void foo(T arg1);
```

Comment: This works great :) even works with subclasses and lvalue references

Answer (score 3):

You want `decltype`, not `typeid`. You use `typeid` to get run-time type information, whereas `decltype` will give you the type of an expression at compile-time.

```
std::is_same<decltype(*arg1), Foo>::value
```

Note, if you don't need a call with a type that doesn't point at a `Foo` to fall back to a different overload, then you might prefer to use `static_assert` instead of `std::enable_if`:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T arg1) {
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(*arg1), Foo>::value, "Performing indirection with an object of type T must give a Foo");
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A template is way too complicated:

```
void foo(Foo&);
void foo(const Foo&);
void foo(Foo*);
void foo(const Foo*);
```

and dispatch accordingly.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {};
struct Any {
    operator Foo () const { return Foo(); }
};

void foo(const Foo&) {
    std::cout << "Hello Foo\n";
}

int main() {
    Any a;
    foo(a);
}
```

Comment: Well as I said `foo` can take any type that dereferences to `Foo`.

Comment: ...dereference is not casting